# import tensorflow failed in eclipse

Tags: tensorflow

Installed tensorflow for python3.5 on Mac, try the testing code as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf

hello = tf.constant("test")
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

It is working when run it from the terminal.
But if I run it from eclipse, will get this exception:

```
warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"/usr/local/bin/python3.5" "/Users/leitian/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.3.0.201610121612/pysrc/setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build.
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 2109)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/leitian/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.3.0.201610121612/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 1531, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Users/leitian/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.3.0.201610121612/pysrc/pydevd.py", line 938, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Users/leitian/.p2/pool/plugins/org.python.pydev_5.3.0.201610121612/pysrc/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 25, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/leitian/code/python/eclipse-ws/TestTF/Hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 60, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so
  Reason: image not found


Error importing tensorflow.  Unless you are using bazel,
you should not try to import tensorflow from its source directory;
please exit the tensorflow source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter
from there.
```

Can anyone help here?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't help you with the Eclipse issue, but the error message means that the Tensorflow shared library could not be found. One way you might be able to fix this is to set the enviroment variable `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to the directory containing `_pywrap_tensorflow.so`. Hope that helps!

Comment: I have found the reason: I installed the GPU version earlier by mistake, but it was not removed completely.